# Solution of Volterra convolution-type integral equation

Tags: integral-equations

The convolution-type Volterra integral equation of the first kind

$f(t) = \int_a^t k(t-t')\,x(t')\,dt'  \qquad t\in [0,\infty]$

can be solved (at least formally) by applying the Laplace transformation $L$ to obtain

$F(s) = K(s)X(s)$

(where the upper case denotes the Laplace transformed lower case function) and then applying the inverse Laplace Transform $L^{-1}$ to obtain

$x(t) = L^{-1} [F(s)/K(s)]$.

My question is: Can this method of solution be modified to applying to $f(t)$ which are defined only on some finite interval $[0,T]$?

Comment: If you modify it this way it becomes a Fredholm integral equation of the first kind.

Comment: Mhenni, I should have stated that $0 < t' < t < T$. Then it stays Volterra, right?